# DataTable with several type of checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, datatables

Am using datatable with checkbox. have serveral checkbox with two type of class name.Need to check all checkbox based on class name

This is my code :-

```
      var exampless = $('.table1').DataTable({
        responsive: true,
        "searching": false,
        "ordering": false,
        "lengthChange": false,
         "bInfo" : false,
         className: 'select-checkbox',
     });
     $(".alluser").click(function () {
        var cols = exampless.column(0).nodes(),
        state = this.checked;

        for (var i = 0; i < cols.length; i += 1) {
        cols[i].querySelector(".User").checked = state;
        }
     });
```

Getting this error

> TypeError: cols[i].querySelector(...) is null

Answer (score 0):

See if this example helps:
http://live.datatables.net/legemixi/1/edit

The key part of the code to check all is this code which use DataTables API's:

```
$('input.checkall').on('change', function () {
  var checked = this.checked;  //get checked state of Check All or Check Page checkbox
  $('.filter-ck', table.cells().nodes()).prop('checked',this.checked);
```

The example also show how to check all on only the page displayed.  Also it updates the checkbox data value of 1 or 0 depending on the checkbox state.